# Is $ ... $ okay to use, while $$ ... $$ is not recommended?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are \( and \) preferable to $?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)

According to [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), `$$ ... $$` should not be used. My understanding is, it is because `$$ ... $$` is not supported by `amsmath`, so using it may cause inconsistent spacing. But, what about `$ ... $`, shouldn't it be avoided as well? Is `$ ... $` supported by `amsmath`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both display math `$$...$$` and inline math `$...$` is valid in LaTeX. In fact, their accepted counterparts `\[...\]` and `\(...\)` are defined in terms of the former. However, `\[...\]` just adds a little flair in term of spacing around the environment by performing some checks. The use of `\(...\)` is almost exactly like using `$...$`. To see why this is the case, view their definitions in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\({\relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else$\fi}
\def\){\relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}
```

Of course, you can also use more contextual phrases to do the same thing: `\math...\endmath` is an environment pair (similarly, `\begin{math}...\end{math}`) that is defined as equivalent to `\(...\)`, and also `\displaymath...\enddisplaymath` (similarly, `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}`):

```
\let\math=\(
\let\endmath=\)
\def\displaymath{\[}
\def\enddisplaymath{\]\@ignoretrue}
```

In answer to your question: Both forms are **usable** by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), but it actually only **supports** the use of `\[...\]`, since it redefines these to mean something different:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

Convention, over the years, has shifted to using `\[...\]` for display math and a mixture of using `\(...\)` or `$...$` for inline math.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `$...$` is perfectly fine to use for inline math.

See [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)

Comment: According to a comment by Joseph Wright (to the accepted answer in the linked thread) “perfectly fine” isn’t quite right. If (when) LaTeX3 ever comes out, the `$…$` may no longer be supported. So in the interest of future compatibility, `\(…\)` should be preferred.