# How to avoid line break with \[ \] syntax

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I know I should not use `$$ $$` for math equations since it's deprecated, and instead I should use `\[` and `\]`. But with this notation, every formula I type is centered on a new line. How can I have the formula in the line of text?

Comment: Either with `$ $` or `\( \)`, these are for inline equations.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to typeset? You do know the difference between text-math and display-math right? Text-math as Dox mentioned is written as a part of the running text, and can be automatically line broken at certain types of math. Display math on the other hand (i.e. ``\[...\]`` plus the envs from the `amsmath` package) offer no automatic linebreaking, that has to be done by hand.

Comment: `$$` also makes a centred display.

Comment: If you decide to use `\(..\)` you better load `fixltx2e` package.

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/is-okay-to-use-while-is-not-recommended

Comment: @Manuel We are going to sort that for the next LaTeX2e release (I hope) :-)