# Using math without "$...$" or "\( ... \)"

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to use  math commands in text without using `$..$` or `\(..\)` as for example:

```
 ... testing \alpha more text
```

Comment: When writing math symbols you'll want math spacing, so instead of avoiding writing certain things you should make it easier to write certain things, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30631/replace-the-macro-with-the-macros-prefer-the-way-latex/30644#30644

Comment: Also explained in [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Answer (score 20):

While it's possible to coax LaTeX into allowing

```
... testing \alpha more text
```

or similar input, this opens the door to

```
... testing \alpha+\beta more text
```

or, even worse, to

```
... testing \alpha-\beta more text
```

which would give something we are, regrettably, used to see in poorly typeset documents. Getting trained into writing

```
\(\alpha\)
```

will help the typist to keep math properly segregated, so that TeX will be able to apply its special math processing.

### Added

If all you need is to type Greek words, as opposed to math symbols, the road is different: put

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
```

in your preamble. If you already use **babel**, add the `greek` option as the first one. Then

```
\textgreek{ABGDEZHJIKLMNXOPRSTUFQYW abgdezhjiklmnxoprstufqyw}
```

will typeset the Greek lowercase alphabet. The "tonos" can be input as a prefix apostrophe:

```
\textgreek{Ag'ia Sof'ia (Kwnstantino'upolh)}
```

will print Αγία Σοφία (Κωνσταντινούπολη)

There's also support for polytonic Greek.

Answer (score 5):

All answers have mentioned using the alpha from the math font. If you are looking for typesetting a Greek word then you should use alpha from a text font. I don't know about LaTeX, but in ConTeXt there are two ways to use Greek letters from the text fonts. For both cases, you need to use a text font that has Greek letters (TeX Gyre Fonts have that, LM does not).

```
\setupbodyfont[palatino]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[width=6cm, offset=2mm]
There are two ways to get Greek letters in text mode:
\startitemize[n][headstyle=bold]
  \head Type them directly

    αβγδε \unknown

  \head Use \type{\greek...} macros

    \greekalpha\greekbeta\greekgamma\greekdelta\unknown
\stopitemize

Notice that text Greek symbols αβγδε differ from math Greek symbols $αβγδε$.
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will need first to store the original commands using `\let`:

```
 \let\storeAlpha=\alpha
```

and then redefine the command, here is a minimal:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\let\storeAlpha=\alpha
\renewcommand\alpha{\relax\ifmmode{\storeAlpha}\else{$\storeAlpha$}\fi\xspace}
%% another way is to use \ensuremath

\let\storeBeta=\beta
\renewcommand\beta{\ensuremath{\beta}}

This is an \alpha and an $\alpha$ and an \(\alpha\) and a \beta.
\end{document}
```

The `\ifmmode` checks if TeX is in mathmode, if is true it will use the original command, otherwise the `$..$` are inserted.

Comment: You could use `\ensuremath` here to make life a bit less wordy.

Comment: @Joseph I will add a note, thought this one would make a good example to illustrate math mode, but you right it is very wordy.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but it is not possible to write math control sequences without placing them in a math environment such as `$...$` Or `$$...$$` or `\[...\]`. The only way I can see you doing this is by defining the control sequence you want using some of the several methods, but I will choose to use the `ensuremath`, to make sure that no matter what environment you are using your math commands in, the compiler will not complain to you and give you millions of errors.

Such as:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\alp{\ensuremath{\alpha} }

\begin{document}

This is a test that \alp works inside of the text-mode environment.

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: alpha]

So this is one way to get the job done.

Hope this helped.

**EDIT:** As egreg kindly pointed out to me. The `$$...$$` should not be used for display math instead use  -> `\[...\]` as an "equivalent" (minus the spacing issues `$$...$$` gives) alternative.

Comment: Since you are talking about LaTeX, please don't mention `$$...$$`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Even though I stopped using it myself, some others still do, but I shall not encourage it I guess.