# Working with templates

Tags: templates, best-practices

I have just read the wonderful article [LaTeX templates](http://latex-community.org/know-how/429-latex-templates) and realized that I have tried to practice this approach but there is one technical aspect which I don't know how to tackle. I am talking about how to actually *use* these pre-prepared templates. The main issue is how to easily load them, when one starts writing a new document. The simplest approach would be to have one local central repository of templates (and maybe their revisions as Stefan Kottwitz suggested in [his post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/latex-general/templates/)), and when ever `template.tex` is needed *copy* it to a new directory dedicated to the new document. However, this misses some of the modularity of LaTeX, isn't it?.

When working with a document personalized class file, which is stored somewhere where TeX can find, the user simply has to specify the class' name and it is at his disposal, regardless of where the class is stored for example. This is not the case with templates. So my question is essentially the following: *What is the best way to use LaTeX templates?* How should I store them? Where should I store them? How should I use them at the end of the day? Shouldn't a template be "exported" into a class file? If so, the what is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I simply put my custom `.sty` files in a specific directory and then include them in my `.tex` file via a relative path. This makes it very clear in the the source which ones are my custom versions.

Comment: Are you considering `.sty` as a template? I guess these are two different things. Maybe, due to my poor understanding, I referred to class files, while they are also something else.

Comment: Yes, for `.sty` files I do as above, and for `.tex` files which are mostly blank but are reusable for a particular setup that I use often, I store them in the specific place depending on the IDE I use -- as per @R.Schumacher answer below. For `TeXShop` I store them in `~/Library/TeXShop/Stationery/` and then I can access the file from `File/New from Stationary`, and for `TeXWorks` I put them in `~/Library/TeXworks/templates/` and access it via `File/New from Template`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Snippet managers

A flexible and powerful way of working with templates is to use a snippet manager. In [Replace the `$$ ... $$` macro with the `\[ ... \]` macros? - Prefer the way LaTeX lays it out, but `$` are faster to write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30631/replace-the-macro-with-the-macros-prefer-the-way-late/30644#30644) you find a simple explanation of how a snippet manager works. What you do is simply to store each template as a separate snippet and use the power of the snippet manager to modify it on expansion.

### YASnippet

Here is an example with [YASnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/), a snippet manager for Emacs. The following steps are how to create a simple article template:

1. Enter the mode you want the snippets in. In this case I guess it is LaTeX-mode.
2. Do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `yas/new-snippet`.
3. Enter a name for the snippet.
4. You will now get a chance to edit the snippet. Mark everything by doing <kbd>C-x h</kbd>, then kill it by <kbd>C-w</kbd>.
5. You will now have an empty snippet. Paste the following into it and make sure the snippet ends after `\end{document}` and *not* on a new line:

   ```
   # -*- mode: snippet -*-
   # name: article
   # key: arttemp
   # --
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[${1:english}]{babel}

   \title{${2:Title}}
   \author{${3:Author}}

   \begin{document}

   \maketitle

   $0

   \end{document}
   ```
6. Do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to save and load the snippet.

Now you can use the snippet in LaTeX-mode by writing `arttemp` and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Note how `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$0` defines tab stops and that the three first has default values which can be overridden. Here is an animation that shows how the snippet works:

[image: Animation of the snippet above]

Obviously the snippet in the example is a very simple snippet. One snippet I use as a template for articles is 172 lines long. It contains `\usepackage`s for the packages I commonly use, package configuration and macro definitions for macros I commonly use. For more information on how to write snippets see [the documentation](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-development.html).

With YASnippet your snippets are stored as files. The manual describes how you can [organize snippets](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html). I keep my snippets in ~/.emacs.d/mysnippets and load them by the following in my .emacs:

```lisp
(setq yas/root-directory "~/.emacs.d/mysnippets"); Develop and keep personal snippets under ~/emacs.d/mysnippets
(yas/load-directory yas/root-directory); Load the snippets
```

By syncing ~/.emacs.d/mysnippets between computers I get the same snippets on all of them.

Comment: Ok, that _do not use place a blank line after `\end{document` is **very** important_

Comment: BTW: I find the default for `\begin{environment}...\end{environment}` counter intuitive and anoying. Though it was easy to fix. Very handy tip.

Comment: @daleif I emphasized the 'not' to make it clearer. What default are you referring to?

Comment: @NN: that one should write `begin` and hit `TAB`, it is the same thing as in TeXnicCenter, and I find it un-intuitive. I changed it to match `\begin` and removed the `\n` from the start of the inserted text (I edited the `.el` file.

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to use say `\begin{fig` as the key?

Comment: @daleif It seems you cannot use `\` and `{` in keys and it does not help to escape them. Why not do without such special characters? After all, it is easier to write non-special characters.

Comment: Because `\begin{fig<TAB>` is easier to remember, and more intuitive for new users. Have you tried the `TeXnicCenter` equivalent? It has a popup interface, if I type `doc` it ask if I want `\begin/end{document}`, fine. But if a new user is using TC and is writing `\begin{doc` and say yes, then he gets `\begin{doc\begin{document}`. That is not userfriendly. At least TeXMaker gets it right.

Comment: It is about ease of use. The less one has to remember the better.

Comment: @daleif I think the keys `fig` for figure or `env` for any environment are easier to remember. They are also faster to write and efficiency is a reason for using YASnippet. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/9083046/789593 and http://superuser.com/a/395062/87552 for inspiration on creating snippets.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up simple templating system with lua.

Sample template `sample.tpl`:

```
---
title = "Sample document",
extra_packages = "cmap",
encoding="utf8",
class = "article"
---
\documentclass{${class}}
\usepackage[${encoding}]{inputenc}
\usepackage{${extra_packages}}
\title{${title}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
${content}
\end{document}
```

In header delimited with `---` strings, default variables are set. They are then included in the code with `${variable_name}`. You can overide the variables in the document:

```
---
title = "Hello world",
extra_packages="lipsum"
---
\section{First one}

\lipsum[1-4]
```

Now the script `luatextemplating.lua`

```lua
kpse.set_program_name("luatex")
-- Helper functions
-- interp: simple templating
-- usage: print( "${name} is ${value}" % {name = "foo", value = "bar"} )
function interp(s, tab)
  return (s:gsub('($%b{})', function(w) return tab[w:sub(3, -2)] or w end))
end
getmetatable("").__mod = interp

-- Parse page variables
function table.unserialize(s)
        local getTableFromString = loadstring('return '..s)
        local t = assert(getTableFromString())
        if type(t) ~= 'table' then return end
        return t
end

function string:split(pat)
  pat = pat or '%s+'
  local st, g = 1, self:gmatch("()("..pat..")")
  local function getter(segs, seps, sep, cap1, ...)
    st = sep and seps + #sep
    return self:sub(segs, (seps or 0) - 1), cap1 or sep, ...
  end
  return function() if st then return getter(st, g()) end end
end
-- 
function parseInputFile(filename)
  local f=io.open(filename)
  local s = f:read("*a")
  f:close()
  return parseInput(s)
end
function parseInput(s)
  local start = s:find("---") + 3
  local header_end= s:find("---",start)
  local header= s:sub(start,header_end-1)
  local content= s:sub(header_end+3)
  return table.unserialize("{"..header.."}"),content
end

-- Execution

local arg_message=[[
luatextemplating - generate TeX files from simple templates
usage: 
  luatextemplating templatefile inputfile
result is printed to the stdout
]]


if #arg < 2 then
  texio.write_nl(arg_message)
  return 0
end

local main_header, template = parseInputFile(arg[1])
local file_header, content= parseInputFile(arg[2])

for k, v in pairs(file_header) do
  main_header[k]=v
end

main_header["content"]=content
print(template % main_header)
```

After running `texlua luatextemplating.lua path/to/templates/sample.tpl sample.tex` you get this document at the standard output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Hello world}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First one}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to enable template is to use the facilities provided in the different IDEs.

For example: In TexMaker, you want to keep the templates all in a single folder structure separate from your working folders. Then you use the file-new for existing file option to get the template.  Then save it into the working folder.   I have my students develop and keep individual project templates this way.

Additionally the IDE TexnicCenter has a similar feature, except you are required to carefully follow the directions in the manual to get the template feature to work.  The most important direction is that a new directory must be created in the structure for your template files.  (edit:  The template feature in TexnicCenter prevents you from accidentally changing a template when you save as.)

I would expect that other IDE have similar features provided.

Answer (score 3):

Like R. Schumacher I feel that templating is the domain of the IDE and not LaTeX itself.  I use TeXShop, and it supports templating through the filesystem.  Files put in `~/Library/TeXShop/Templates` are loaded into the Templates menu on the editor window so you can pull them out whenever.  Snippets (which I guess is pretty much the same thing but not an entire file) are implemented through TexShop's macro editor.

A [TeX Directory Structure compliant](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/tds/tds.html) place to put your templates might be `${TEXMFHOME}/source/templates/`, then the format (`tex/`, `latex/`, etc.

Many times I see people on this site talking about *templates* when I think they are really talking about *classes*.  What is the difference?  To me, if a LaTeX file provides the look and feel—and macros to facilitate the formatting—of a specific type of document it is a class.  If it provides boilerplate content to be re-used or changed as necessary then it's a template. To put it another way, if the provided file all belongs in the preamble it is a class, and if it it includes document text it's a template.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Emacs and file templates (and just for the completeness): I am using the `auto-insert-tkld`-Package since ages.  You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/kloper/env/blob/master/emacs/auto-insert-123/auto-insert-tkld.el).

Basicly, this package is used, to provide different file templates, which are inserted, whenever you open a nonexistent file in Emacs.  This package is configured in the usual emacs way, by means of elisp variables.  Namely, you define, which file type is filled by which template.  Auto-Insert-TKLD manages also a search path, giving you the opportunity, to have different templates for different projects for the same type of files.

When opening a nonexistent file, for which an appropriate template was defined, the template will be inserted in the buffer.  While inserting, some special codes are recognised; e.g. `%U` will be replaced by the full user name, `%a` will be replaced bye the mail address of the user, actually running Emacs, and so on.

Furthermore, Auto-Insert TKLD is able, to ask user defined questions in Emacs minibuffer and insert the answer into the template, customising it further on.  This makes a pretty easy method, of powerful customised templates.

But you can go even further, by using the special characters `%(` and `%)` to encapsule ordinary elisp code, which is evaluated, when the template is inserted into the buffer.  This makes very powerful templates, but you have to deal with coding Emacs Lisp, of course!

This package deals explicitly with templates, which are inserted, whenever you start working on a **nonexistent** file. It does not support inserting code snippets into an existing buffer, as does the `YASnippet` package, mentioned above.  But you can combine those two very well.