# Does AucTeX Autocomplete?

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

The quick start guide for AUCTeX says

> As nearly everywhere in AUCTeX, you can use the TAB or SPC key to get a list of available level names, and to auto-complete what you started typing.

Which tantalizingly makes me thing AUCTeX has an auto-complete feature. But pressing TAB does nothing. I apologize for the simple question, but I've spent more time searching for it than I am ever likely to save so this is a last resort before I give up on it.

So, is there in fact an auto-complete feature in Emacs AUCTeX? How does one turn it on if so?

Edit: I just figured out `M-TAB` is problematic since it is bound to a OS GUI action. I saw a website discuss this problem and it notes that there are two key bindings which are supposed to be equivalent: `c-[ c-I` and `ESC TAB`. Except these for some reason give me dictionary spelling corrections for the word I wrote which is not exactly what I was expecting.

Comment: Can you please share the way of turning off this flyspell mode? I tried the two methods given elsewhere on this site ....Latex-mode-hook 'turn-off-flyspell and '(flyspell-mode f)

Comment: Why are you trying to use `M-TAB` for autocomplete?  As you quoted: AUCTeX uses `TAB` or `SPC` to prompt for possible autocomplete actions (i.e., no `Meta-<something>`).

Comment: @jon [The manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Completion.html) lists `M-Tab` as the default binding for `TeX-complete-symbol`.

Comment: @N.N. -- huh, never noticed that.  I always just use `C-c C-m` or `C-c <RET>` (if I want to insert something like `\footnote`) at which point `<TAB>` and `<SPC>` will do tab-completion to the point where further disambiguation is needed (e.g., there are a lot of known commands starting with `\foot-`).

Answer (score 32):

It does have auto-complete powers.  (It has more than any one person knows about.)  Try, e.g., `C-c C-m` (for calling macros like `\footnote` or `\ref`); type the letter 's' and hit TAB.  The rest will become clear.  `C-c C-e` will prompt for for starting new environments. And so on.

If you use AUCTeX with reftex, try things like `C-c [` to prompt you for a bibliographical `\cite{<key>}` command.

You should skim the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.index.html) for the sections that are most relevant for your work.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out why the key binding given in the manual wasn't working. Flyspell is bound to the same key as the auto-complete function so it has to be disabled for auto-complete to work.

Comment: @AwnaniMaus You should post that as an answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please share the way of turning off this flyspell mode? I tried the two methods given elsewhere on this site ....Latex-mode-hook 'turn-off-flyspell and '(flyspell-mode f)

Comment: @Anusha -- Let's start with this: Can you turn off `flyspell-mode` when you are in a `.tex` buffer with the following command: `M-x flyspell-mode RET`?  (If it is on, this should turn it off; if it is off, this should turn it on.)

Comment: @jon Thanks. This works. I guess autocomplete in emacs means working with macros or defined key bindings.

Comment: @Anusha -- I believe so, though you could define some of your own in your `.emacs`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `C-[` is not mentioned in the current manual. Maybe it is bound to something else in the most recent version. It would be great if you can add the information which command `C-[` is supposed to execute.

Comment: @bluenote10 --  Oops!  It's `C-c [`, not `C-[`.  Sorry about that. Anyway, if you use the *correct* key sequence, it should (if you are running `reftex` with AUCTeX) prompt you for a set of `\cite`-related commands.  Will edit....

Answer (score 10):

As you mention AUCTeX has an auto-complete function which per default is bound to `M-Tab` which conflicts with many window managers. The function is called [`TeX-complete-symbol`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Completion.html) and you can use it via `M-x TeX-complete-symbol` or bind it to any other key you prefer. By inserting the following into your .emacs you bind it to `C-Tab` in LaTeX-mode (i.e. AUCTeX):

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (local-set-key [C-tab] 'TeX-complete-symbol)))
```

Still, I think it may be more effective to use `C-c Ret` (for `TeX-insert-macro`), `C-c C-e` (for `LaTeX-environment`) and [YASnippet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51250/5701).

Answer (score 7):

As of recently, AucTEX seems to work out of the box with [Predictive Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode), providing "full "Intellisense" features for writing LaTeX documents in Emacs." (See the [AucTeX entry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX#toc12) on the EmacsWiki for more info). I have not tried this yet, but surely will when I get home in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emacs's native Dynamic Abbrev Expansion for most auto completions.

Just try `M-/`. You can keep repeating `M-/` to cycle through all possible completions.

For more details: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html