# AUCTeX style for siunitx

Tags: emacs, siunitx, auctex

Is there any `AUCTeX` style for `siunitx`? If not are there any simple tricks which make it more easy to type `siunitx` commands in `emacs`. For example if I type `C-c C-m SI` it inserts just `\SI{}` with one pair of braces and not two. In particular it doesn't give a prompt to insert the arguments.

Comment: You could use [YASnippet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51250/5701) to insert siunitx macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, just an example:

One can create a custom `siunitx.el` file and put this into a `TeX-style-path` such that `TeX` can find it.

To see what paths are in `TeX-style-path` just do `M-x describe variable` RET `TeX-style-path` for example: `~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto` is usually in `TeX-style-path` (if the directory doesn't exist, one have to create it).

The `siunitx.el` file contains for example the following:

```lisp
;;; siunitx.el --- AUCTeX style file for Siunitx
(TeX-add-style-hook "siunitx"
              (function
               (lambda ()
             (TeX-add-symbols
              '("SI"       "Value" "Unit")
                      '("ang"      "Angle")
              ))))
```

If you change the `siunitx.el` file and want to apply the changes to your current buffer editing a file which uses `siunitx`, just press `C-c C-n` in this buffer.

To use it type for example `C-c C-m` `RET` `SI` `RET`. Then emacs asks you for the value and the unit.