# Convert TeX display math style ($$ MATH $$) to LaTeX (\begin{equation*} MATH \end{equation*})

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to write a script (in `emacs lisp`) to convert `TeX` display math style like, e.g.,

```
$$
x + y = z
$$
```

into the `LaTeX`

```
\begin{equation*}
x + y = z
\end{equation*}
```

To get my purpose I imagined this algorithm:

1. While scanning the file for the `"$$"` strings, I would replace temporarily, once at time, the `"$$"` string with `"$$\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH"` where `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH` is something like:

   ```
   \newcommand{\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH}{\mathchoice{\wlog{DISPLAY MATH OK}}{}{}{}}
   ```

   (this is necessary to avoid false positives like "$x,$$y,$")
2. At this point I'd compile my `.tex` file to generate the `.log` file and scanning it for my target string.
3. After removing the `"\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH"` string, if "DISPLAY MATH OK" I would perform my replacement.

My questions are:

1. Can I approach my task in a faster way? I mean, e.g., without the need to fully compile my `.tex` file for each instance of `"$$"`.
2. Is there a tool that can do it already?

I'm open to any suggestion.

Comment: If you have your `$$` in a form like above what prevents you from simply using search & replace to transform `$$\n` into `\[\n` (or something different)?

Comment: @TeXnician, this is the way I've done it until now. I'm trying to automate this task.

Comment: My impression is that this is more a Emacs rather than TeX question.

Comment: @egreg I don't thing so, because I'm searching, e.g., for a LaTeX way to speed up the compilation of the `.tex` file. In emacs I would have used the syntactic highlighting but it not enough strong.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but you could perform the regex replacement `\$\$\([^$]+\)\$\$` → `\\begin{equation}\1\\end{equation}`. This does not match the false positive you mention because it only searches for `$$…$$` with no `$` between them. (It does fail for `$x,$$y,$$z,$`, but it seems unlikely something like that would appear in your document.)

Comment: @Circumscribe, It is useful. In a "paranoic mode" I'll need to temporarily mask improbable escaped \$ in the math contents but it should work.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: I don't expect your proposed algorithm would work by the way because every branch of a `\mathchoice` is executed (but only one is printed). This means that you'll see "DISPLAY MATH OK" in your log irrespective of whether the `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH` occurs in a display environment or not.

Comment: If you add `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\GenericWarning{\relax}{DISPLAY MATH}}` to your preamble TeX will print `DISPLAY MATH on input line <line number>.` for every display equation though.

Comment: @Circumscribe, you're right about the mathchoice behaviour. I didn't expect it. I wonder if this issue can be approched by the LaTeX side.

Comment: Alternatively: `\newcommand{\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH}{}` together with `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\renewcommand{\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH}{\wlog{DISPLAY MATH OK}}}` would work. This way `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH ` does nothing, but it is redefined to print your message when it is used inside a display environment. (It will also print this message if used inside a `text{…}` in a display environment though.)

Comment: @Circumscribe, if you like, please articulate your hints in an answer to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if any of these really answer your question. I like the regex solution best (and I expect it'll nearly always) work, but if that's the answer the question is kind of off-topic.

Comment: I know you want to do this in Emacs lisp, but many years ago I wrote a perl script to do this and you might find it helpful at least in terms of figuring out the regex.  You can find it at https://github.com/loopspace/debuck

Comment: @LoopSpace this could also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly the same thing but [math mode - Replace the `$$ ... $$` macro with the `\[ ... \]` macros? - Prefer the way LaTeX lays it out, but `$` are faster to write - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30631/replace-the-macro-with-the-macros-prefer-the-way-late?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what the best way to do this is, but here are a couple of suggestions.

1. Since you're using Emacs, you could try the following regex replacement:

   ```
   \$\$\([^$]+\)\$\$ → \\begin{equation}\1\\end{equation}
   ```

   This matches anything of the form `$$…$$`, where `…` can be any sequence of characters (including newlines) that does not contain `$`. It does not fail for the false positive which you mention (`$x,$$y,$`), but it would fail for something like `$x,$$y,$$z,$`.

   Just to be safe you may want to first replace `\\` by something unique and then replace `\$` by something unique (both non-regex) and undo these replacements afterwards. The first replacement is to prevent the replacement of `\$` in `\\$` and the second is to prevent replacement of `\$$` when `\$` is a literal $ sign and the second starts or ends an equation.
2. If you would like to know the line numbers for all display math environments you could add

   ```
   \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\GenericWarning{\relax}{DISPLAY MATH}}
   ```

   to your preamble. This prints `DISPLAY MATH on input line <line>` for every display equation.

   (The contents of `\everydisplay` is inserted at the start of every display environment. You can add something to it with `\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay<addition>}`. )
3. Your `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH` algorithm doesn't actually work because each of the branches of `\mathchoice` is always executed (though only one is printed). Consequently, `DISPLAY MATH OK` will be printed irrespective of whether this macro is called from within a display environment.

   If you want to go this route you may want to instead try something like

   ```
   \let\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH\empty %% <- does nothing
   \makeatletter %% <- make @ usable in command names
   \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay
     \@ifnextchar\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH{\wlog{DISPLAY MATH OK}}{}}
   \makeatother  %% <- revert @
   ```

   You should add this **at the end** of your preamble (and in particular after loading `amsmath` or maybe even right after `\begin{document}` (to be safe). It prints `DISPLAY MATH OK` whenever the very first thing that appears in an equation is `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH`. It may be incompatible with some packages (if they change `\everydisplay` during runtime, though I'm not aware of any).

   Alternatively you could try

   ```
   \let\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH\empty %% <- does nothing
   \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay
     \renewcommand\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH{\wlog{DISPLAY MATH OK}}}
   ```

   This way `\TESTIFDISPLAYMATH` normally does nothing, but it is redefined to write `DISPLAY MATH OK` to the log file whenever it is used inside a display math environment. It will also trigger when used inside a `\text{…}` inside such an environment though, so it's still not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Not heavily tested, but a lisp function can look like this.  It replaces all occurrences of `$$` which are in a line of their own with an `equation*` environment.  If invoked with <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd>, it also looks for inline `$$` and replaces them.

```el
(defun GN/fix-math ()
  "Search and replace TeX's $$ with LaTeX's \"equation*\" environment.
Replaces only $$ in single lines.  If invoked with `C-u', then
also looks after $$ which are inline.  User is asked for
confirmation then."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)          
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let ((kill-whole-line nil))
        (while (and (re-search-forward (concat "^[ \t]*" (regexp-quote "$$") "[ \t]*$") nil t)
                    (texmathp))
          (beginning-of-line)
          (kill-line)
          (insert "\\begin{equation*}")
          (re-search-forward (concat "^[ \t]*" (regexp-quote "$$") "[ \t]*$") nil t)
          (beginning-of-line)
          (kill-line)
          (LaTeX-close-environment)
          (forward-line -1)
          (LaTeX-fill-environment nil)))))
  (when current-prefix-arg
    (save-excursion
      (save-restriction
        (widen)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward (regexp-quote "$$") nil t)
          (when (yes-or-no-p "Replace $$? ")
            (delete-char -2)
            (newline)
            (save-excursion
              (end-of-line -1)
              (delete-horizontal-space))
            (insert "\\begin{equation*}")
            (newline)
            (indent-according-to-mode)
            (re-search-forward (regexp-quote "$$") nil t)
            (delete-char -2)
            (LaTeX-close-environment)
            (forward-line -1)
            (LaTeX-fill-environment nil)))))))
```

Comment: Where are the `LaTeX-*` functions defined?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi - In `latex.el` provided by AUCTeX.  I've presumed that you're using it.